# KeyEvents and Focus JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I am super confused right now. 
I've created a Pane in the fxml code and set an onKeyPressed event.

```
pane.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
       System.out.println( "I'm here");
       jump( event);
   }
});
```

This didn't work. Pane didn't catch any KeyEvents. Never printed "I'm here". 
Then I wanted to set the scene's onKeyPressed, which works, but I have to do it in the controller as the things I want to handle during a key press must be done in the Controller.

Then I called `pane.getScene().setOnKeyPressed()` but that gave a `nullPointerException`, as I found out that I have to call it outside `initialize()`.

So I created a Button and attached an onAction event to it, which prints out the Scene of my Pane, to try if it really works.

```
@FXML
public void printScene() {
    System.out.println( pane.getScene());
}
```

When I clicked the button, it printed out the Scene of my Pane as it should have. But then, I realized that my Pane now catches KeyEvents. I have changed nothing except add a button using Fxml and now the Pane catches KeyEvents? When I comment out the code for the button, the Pane doesn't catch KeyEvents anymore

```
<Button onAction="#printScene"/>
```

This is all the code I have for the Button.

Note: I also tried `pane.requestFocus()` and `pane.SetFocusTraversable( true)` which didn't work either. But adding a button suddenly makes it work? I am so confused.

ENTIRE CODE:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
    primaryStage.setScene( scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}

public class Controller {

@FXML private Pane pane;
@FXML private Rectangle cube;

public void initialize() {
    pane.requestFocus();
    pane.setFocusTraversable( true);
    pane.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println( "I'm here");
            jump( event);
        }
    });
    System.out.println( pane.getScene());
}
}

//FXML Code
<Pane fx:controller="sample.Controller" fx:id="pane"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

<Rectangle width="800" height="20" layoutY="580" fill="green"/>
<Rectangle fx:id="cube" width="40" height="40" layoutX="5" layoutY="540"/>
<!--<Button />-->
</Pane>
```

Uncommenting button makes Pane gain focus, and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure why adding the button gives focus to the pane, or why `pane.requestFocus()` didn't work (you need to post a [MCVE] to get that answered). The best way to do this is to register a listener on the scene, which you can do where you create the scene. At that point it should be possible to get a reference to the controller too, so you can call a method on the controller from the handler.

Comment: I will post all of the code as soon as I can, thanks for the help. Also I called for requestFocus in the initialize() method, maybe thats why it didnt work?

Comment: @James_D I've posted the entire code. I'd be glad if you could take a look ^^

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. I know that creating a control instance will force loading of CSS. I wonder if for some reason `requestFocus()` doesn't work unless the node is either part of a scene or CSS has been loaded - I would have to dig through the source code to figure out if that's true. The safer thing to do would appear to be to register the handler on the scene anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on this site, so I may not be very good answering you.

Anyway, I think the error is *applying the event on the pane, try applying it on the scene*.

**EDIT**: I saw that you use `pane.getScene()`; You do not have the scene object?

Comment: I know pane doesnt have focus, thats why I requested focus, which didnt work. Applying it on the scene would work but what Im wondering is why it starting working with the addition of a Button.

Comment: Try printing the pane content before and after the creation of the button. Maybe the scene is not really initialized until you create the Button.

Comment: Commenting nothing else but the <Button/> makes Pane lose focus.

Comment: The `scene` is not even created until after `FXMLLoader.load()` finishes executing, so it would be `null` in the initialize method. The basic idea here is correct: register the handler on the scene, but you need to do that in the `start` method, not in the controller.